# Issues Tracking - Assigned To audience/distribution group

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, audiences, issue-tracking

We are using the issues tracking webpart and would like to set it up so that in the `Assigned To` field, a distribution list is assigned to it.  Evidently, this isn't possible based on the research I've done.  Instead, I assigned this distribution list to an audience and was hoping this would work.  However, this also doesn't work.

Is there any way that these issues can be assigned to an entire distribution list without typing all of the emails out? I know it's possible to send it to multiple people because security groups can be added without any problem.

Comment: Have your AD folks convert the distribution list to a security group and you should be gtg

Comment: This was sort of a last resort.  Is this the only option?

Comment: Yes, distribution lists are not supported in any fashion in SharePoint

Comment: Is there any sort of audience/security group that can be created within SharePoint and have this be targeted?

Comment: people picker columns can use sharepoint groups, thats the best you can do

Answer (score 0):

Apparently there is no way you can import Distribution List into SharePoint. This is because distribution is not security-enabled. Distribution groups cannot be listed in [discretionary access control lists (DACLs)](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc246052.aspx), which are used to define permissions on resources and objects.

If you are only looking for sending emails then store the DL email as a meta data to the Task List and use a SharePoint Workflow to sent emails on Item Added/Updated.